# What is wrong with this If statement nested

Tags: c#, if-statement

Well I have a this IF statement

```
else if (dtpFechaResol.Value.ToShortDateString().Equals(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No) dtpFechaResol.Focus();
}
// This Statement is Jumping  
else if (blNuevo && cbCaja.SelectedIndex >= 0 && txtResolucion.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    ........
}
```

The second `else if` is validate if the first `else if` not satisfy the condition, but if the first `else if` satisfy the condition the second is jumping

How I understand is that in the first statement when validate the `dialogResult` and the answer is Yes the next statement have to validate, but don't

These `else if` are five but this 2 make me the problem

Someone can say me what is my problem

Comment: [if-else (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the `else if` construct works. The first `else if` that evaluates to true is executed, while subsequent `else if` sections within that entire `if...else if` block are ignored.

If you want multiple conditions to be guaranteed to be evaluated, then break them out into separate `if` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

@Karls answer is correct. To visualize how *if-else-if* blocks are executed you need just to add some indentation:

```
if (conditionA)
{
    statementA
}
else if (conditionB)
     {
        statementB
     }
     else if (conditionC)
          {
              statementC
          }
```

I don't like this kind of conditional blocks arrangement. Because actually you have deep nested conditions in method, which are hidden by poor indentation.